How to create document using a specific attribute in reference on mongoose?
Have a user and roles collection, like as:
const roles = mongoose.model('roles',
    new mongoose.Schema({
        name: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        }
    })
);

const users = mongoose.model('users',
    new mongoose.Schema({
        name: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            trim: true,
        },
        roles: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'roles' }]
    })
);

When creating a new user I must associate a role, the problem is that I must first select the roles and then create the user:
users.create({
    name: `Sample user`,
    roles: await roles.find({
        name: { $in: [ 'foo', 'bar' ] }
    }).exec()
});

Is there a way to do this without the need to use a previous search in the repository by passing the objects or ids?
For example, I would like to know if it is possible to insert these values directly into the create user function, something like a subselect inside of an insert in SQL but internally from the database engine without having to pass all the roles to the backend and bring them back to the database over the network, I think this is too redundant and poorly optimized.
Like as:
users.create({
    name: `Sample user`,
    roles: {
        $by: { name: [ 'foo', 'bar' ] }
    }
});


Do you mean something like this?

Unfortunately not with Model.create() as it issues an insertOne and since insertOne is bound to a single collection you can't perform a lookup into the other collection. The findOneAndUpdate method can be passed an upsert:true option which will add a new document if one is not found so you could in theory do a findOneAndUpdate({name: '123'}) and since no name matches you can pass an aggregation pipeline as the second argument which opens up new operators. However, $lookup is an invalid stage here so until MongoDB allow it then it won't be possible to lookup another collection.
